# Не могу передать переменную из функции

Tags: google-maps-api, geocoding, javascript

Столкнулся со странностью -- использую гугловский геокодер для получения адреса, если так:

```
var mypoint = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885, -73.997383);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
    marker;
geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': mypoint
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mypoint,
            map: map // карта уже проиницализирована
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
});
```

То открывается инфоокно на карте с ближайшим адресом, но попытки передать эту строку за пределы функции geocode() - полностью проваливаются. Ни по ссылке, ни через глобальную переменную, ни через ДОМ-контейнер на отдается наружу. Только внутри живет. Это гуглевский прикол, или я ООП слабо знаю?..

Comment: А какую переменную вы хотите передать?

Comment: results[0].formatted_address
если внутри ф-ции написать console.log(results[0].formatted_address);
то он в консоль выдаст адрес, а если попытатся передать куда-то в переменную -- то ундефинед...

Comment: Естественно внутри живет! Переменная, используемая как аргумент локальна для функции. Надо внутри функции присвоить значение results какой-то "внешней" переменной, либо возвратить нужный результат, либо каким-либо способом использовать напрямую внутри функции

Comment: Да? а так не работает:

     var mystuff="";
     geocoder.geocode({'latLng': mypoint}, function(results, status) {
       myStuff=results[0].formatted_address;
     }
     });
     alert(myStuff);

?

Comment: Если не работает то можно ссылку качнуть библиотеку самому попробовать... Очень инетересно стало:)

Comment: в том-то все и дело, что - НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!!

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding?hl=ru-RU
у меня пока два предположения: 
1. гугл намеренно не отдает данные обратного геокодирования, кроме как для своих гуглмаповских компонентов
2. переменная создается быстрее, чем происходит геокодирование, и банально "не успевает" получить ответ

Comment: тут скорее всего сама функция вызвана не была, то есть тут ведь не прямой вызов, а функция передается как аргумент и только подразумевается ее вызов в geocoder.geocode, не факт что произошел... щас поэксперементирую, тоже интересно стало

Comment: вставил в геокод создание маркера, который объявлен вне геокода. занес ему в тайтл нужную строчку, на маркере тайтл всплыл, а за пределами геокодера в консоль лог -- "маркер ундефинед"!!! Таки гугль жлобится

Comment: Посмотри "консоль ошибок". Если гугльский недозагружается ("не успевает"), будут синтаксические ошибки. А вообщеж в гугле такой же джаваскрипт как и у всех, чудес не бывает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, ответ:
в гугле функция геокодирования -- *асинхронная*
т.е. в моем коде приложение в рантайме просто не успевает получить результат, а в консоль вывести - конечно же успевает, понятно почему.
от этой асинхронности получения результата мы и получаем такое странное поведение всей конструкции.
как вариант - использовать коллбэк функцию, но она тоже в итоге не успевала.

поэтому я принял решение на геокодирование от гугля забить, и воспользоваться геокодером яндекс, благо там простой хттп-запрос, который успешно может отработать аякс с учетом времени ожидания ответа.

всем спасибо за ответы и комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
   var mypoint = new google.maps.LatLng(40.730885,-73.997383);
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker;
   var copyOfResults;
   geocoder.geocode({'latLng': mypoint},func);
   function func(results, status) {
       if(status==google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
           marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: mypoint,
               map: map //  Карта уже проиницализирована
           });
           infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
       }
       copyOfResults=results;    
   }
   alert(copyOfResults[0].formatted_address);
```

Помоему должно сработать если не сработает киньте ссылку для скачивания подключаемого скрипта

Comment: сам пример на гугль коде: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse?hl=ru-RU

Answer (score 0):

Да, я был прав! (См. мой послений коммент). Вот демонстрация подобного случая, когда глобальная переменная меняется:

```
function f1(arg1,func)
{
    func(arg1);
}

var test = "";
function f2(arg)
{
    alert("My argument="+arg);
    test = arg;
}

f1("asianirish",f2);

alert("The variable has been changed: " + test);
```

А вот примерчик, когда функция вроде есть, но она не вызвана, поэтому переменная не меняется:

```
function f1(arg1,func)
{
    if(arg1=="asianirish")
        func(arg1);
}

var test = "";
function f2(arg)
{
    alert("My argument="+arg);
    test = arg;
}

f1("asianirish1",f2);

alert("The variable has NOT been changed: " + test);
```

Пример демонстрирует что это МОЖЕТ быть.
Таким образом ответ на вопрос так и остается - нельзя использовать локальную переменную, а ответ на контрпример - внутри geocoder.geocode() пользовательская функция (которую передали как аргумент), в которой меняется значение глобальной переменной (по неизвестным мне причинам), просто не вызывается.
Вот такой мой сказ!

Comment: это все замечательно, но как это может решить мою проблему?.. мне нужно вырвать данные из этой гадюки..

Comment: Тут могу ответить только на поставленный вопрос - найти возможную причину поведения. А вот как решить практическую проблему, мне легче самому сделать, чем заочно бороться с "гадюкой" :)